# What is the default size of a view and what should it be in order to support all orientations

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am creating a view and setting its autoresizemask:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
vc.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
                                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

I am then adding it as a subview.

```
[self.mainView addSubview:flightsHome.view]; //mainView is a UIView IBOutlet which is positioned perfectly
```

This view is used in both portrait and landscape orientations and I want it to resize accordingly.

My question is what frame (size, origin) should I give this view initially and how does Cocoa Touch determine what the initial frame is.

The code above does not resize as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the UIScreen.

here is  a reference to a similar post

[IPhone/IPad: How to get screen width programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655104/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-screen-width-programmatically)