# Issue with frame size of UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on an iPad project, currently it's on Landscape view. And I tried doing:

```
self.view.frame.size.height
```

Why is this always returning 960? While as in landscape the height dimension of the view itself should be 768 right?

What I am trying to do is to **allocInitWithFrame** a **UIToolbar** that is located at the bottom. The **UIToolBar** has a height of 50, so here's what I did which failed:

```
self.bottom_bar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
```

Why is this and how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two postings ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686882/incorrect-frame-window-size-after-re-orientation-in-iphone-or-ipad) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655104/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-screen-width-programmatically)) referenced a similar problem. They both suggest using self.view.bounds instead of self.view.frame.size.width because the bounds change along with the interface orientation.

Comment: I tried chaing it to  self.bottom_bar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-50, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)]; and it's the same thing

Comment: Looking around some more, it looks like [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194504/reporting-incorrect-bounds-in-landscape-mode) had the same problem. I think they solved it  by implementing didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation after the view had loaded and getting the view.bounds there.

Comment: had this problem too. Self.view.bounds works great for me. Cheers