# Getting width/height of the device screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a way in Objective-C to quickly get the width and height of the screen of the device I am in?

I tried doing:

```
CGRect deviceDimension = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

However in an iPad landscape mode it still gives me 768 as the width and 1024 as the height. Any other idea? Or do I have to just use a macro? Basically I am trying to find a way to replace the following macro:

```
#ifdef IPHONE

#define SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT 320
#define SCREEN_WIDTH_LANDSCAPE 480

#else

#define SCREEN_WIDTH_PORTRAIT 768
#define SCREEN_WIDTH_LANDSCAPE 1024

#endif
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655104/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-screen-width-programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get orientation-dependent height and width of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905432/how-to-get-orientation-dependent-height-and-width-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 2):

Combine that with

```
 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] )) { }
```

to distinguish 768x1024  from 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

**See the comment from Richard J. Ross III below.**

<s>You could do it like this:</s>

```
- (CGSize)screenSizeWithRotation
{
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));
}
```