# How to get iOS device screen height and width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IPhone/IPad: How to get screen width programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655104/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-screen-width-programmatically)
>   [How to get orientation-dependent height and width of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905432/how-to-get-orientation-dependent-height-and-width-of-the-screen)

Accounting for the various iOS devices and orientations, what is the simplest approach to getting the current screen resolution, including height and width?

Comment: Or also [How to get orientation-dependent height and width of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905432/how-to-get-orientation-dependent-height-and-width-of-the-screen/7905540#7905540).

Comment: Here you have it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655104/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-screen-width-programmatically

Comment: Neither of those techniques worked for me.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? We can't help you if you don't tell us what your actual problems are.

Comment: @KurtRevis thanks for your feedback. I realize now that I wasn't accounting for the fact that in landscape, the height effectively becomes the width.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[`UIScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) is your friend here.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize now that I wasn't accounting for the fact that in landscape, the height effectively becomes the width.

Comment: If you combine the above with UIDevice, you get a nice ENUM that tells you exactly the orientation of the device. `UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;`

Answer (score 9):

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

That will give you the entire screen's resolution in points, so it would most typically be 320x480 for iPhones. Even though the iPhone4 has a much larger screen size iOS still gives back 320x480 instead of 640x960. This is mostly because of older applications breaking.

Hope it helps you..