# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

`static const CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`
`static const CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;`
`static const CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;`

I understand that screen size is a runtime variable and not known at compile time. I've seen similar questions regarding arrays and other objects, but those don't directly pertain to this.

What is needed is a quick way to access the screen sizes, because thats how I'm doing all of the layout, and I don't want to redefine `screenHeight` and `screenWidth` in all my lazy loading property initializers, such as textFields and labels. I'm aware of `self.view.frame.size` but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

So how can I go about having `screenHeight` and `screenWidth` widely accessible in the code for my app?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14135265/294949

Comment: It is better to adopt autolayout as this will work in split screen mode on an iPad as well as full screen mode

Comment: I've tried autolayout and I'm doing it all programmatically, so autolayout wasn't a very elegant solution

Comment: Programatically or through IB AutoLayout is the way to go. It is much more elegant than calculations using screen width/height since these may break every time Apple releases a new device with a different screen size. It has a learning curve but is much better once you get through that.  Otherwise you could make `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` computed variables

Comment: I see, I'll look into it for my next project then. As for my current project and the original question though, do you mean making these values properties, and then overriding the getter?

Comment: If you really want to go this way, you declare the variables without the `const` modifier, and you assign their values early in the app launch process.  It's the wrong approach on many levels, though.